# How do STD Algorithms handle the lambda pointer?

Tags: c++, lambda, std

so I'm using this small function to print a vector.
It works but I'm trying to understand **how** it works:

```
 void const print_vector(vector<int> const& v)
{
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const int& n) {std::cout << n << " ";});
}
```

How does the "n" variable know to point to the element of the vector?

Any further corrections are appreciated as well

Thank you!

Comment: not worth to add another answer, but I'd like to add that in the following like you can find a possible implementation of for_each where you can see how the lamda is called. Note that the implementation is the same, whether you pass a lambda, function pointer or any other callable. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

Comment: ... just realized that Francois already provided the same link below ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
void const print_vector(vector<int> const& v)
{
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), foo);
}

void foo(const int& n) 
{ 
    std::cout << n << " "; 
}
```

Your lambda is just a shorthand way of declaring the function `foo`.

The address of `foo` is then passed into `for_each`.

`for_each` loops through the vector and calls `foo` each time, passing in the current element as the parameter `n`.

(Note: it's not *exactly* equivalent. The lambda is actually a functor, not a function, but that just confuses matters and makes no difference here.)

Comment: Maybe an [possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each#Possible_implementation) of `for_each` would also help. It shows that `foo` is called in a `for` loop with an argument.

Answer (score 2):

> How does the "n" variable know to point to the element of the vector?

`n` is just an argument of the functor. It is a reference, and it refers to whatever object is passed as an argument to the functor when it is called. `std::for_each` is what calls the functor and passes the argument.

`std::for_each` on the other hand knows to "point" to the element because you passed the begin and end iterators pointing to the vector into it as arguments. `std::for_each` indirects through the begin iterator to get the first element, calls the functor and passes the result of the indirection as an argument. Then `std::for_each` increments the iterator and repeats until the entire range has been iterated.

Answer (score 1):

`n` doesn't point a thing. the algorithm iterates over the container and uses each element in it (by dereferencing the iterators) as an argument for the lambda.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each